# Kiosk Mode for Non-Windows App?

Tags: windows, admin, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I have some GUI I created in QT. I want to have the GUI up and running upon startup and not have the users able to access anything else. I cannot use the built in kiosk mode because it only allows access to Windows applications. How can I do this?

Comment: it is a console application?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Shell Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **For full kiosk mode you need to add your application name in registry at below location**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Key: Shell
Value: c:\myApplication.exe
```